# How to download file from file field in django framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, download, django-views

I want to download a file from the file field through Django views. I tried al lot but didn't get it. Now if I click on the media link it will show in the browser and I want to download it.

Thanks in advance.

***models.py***

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='exam/question')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0):

add your Folder path in setting.py file
Consider my folder name is media and that avaliable in where manage.py file is avaliable.

Add path in MEDIA_ROOT

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**urls.py**
add MEDIA_URL in appname>urls.py if you are access file from app.

```
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #Add Your Path
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Download File**
For localhost
http://localhost:8000/media/media/filename